# C : .so libs and makefile

Tags: c, makefile, libraries

I'm trying to add a .so library to my project, but my knowledge in makefiles are very limited, and I unfortunately don't understand the tutorial I could find...

Here is the structure of my project :

```
/project
    ex1.c
    ex1.h
    ex1_client.c
    ex1_client.h
    /lib
        libmylib.so
```

I need to use mylib in ex1 and ex1_client, two executables, but I don't success in including it in the makefile (and I'm thinking I may not know how to include it in my .c files...)

My makefile is :

```
CC= gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -pthread
RM= rm -f
LFLAGS= -L./lib
LIBS= -lmylib
#Don't know if the following is necessary
LD_LIBRARY_PATH= ./lib

all: ex1 ex1_client

ex1: ex1.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ex1 ex1.o $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

ex1_client: ex1_client.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ex1_client ex1_client.o $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

ex1.o: ex1.c ex1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ex1.c ex1.h

ex1_client.o: ex1_client.c ex1_client.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ex1_client.c ex1_client.h

clean:
    $(RM) *.o ex1 ex1_client *~
```

It doesn't work - seems to don't know where to find mylib, or juste don't know it has something to find.

In addition of that, I didn't write anything about mylib in my .c files... I mean no #include. Probably one of all of the problems.

Explanations about libraries and makefiles seems really hard to me to understand... and please excuse the school-learned english of a young french developper ;)

Comment: The canonical name for libraries is `libXYZ.so`; GCC knows this, and is expecting flags of the form `-lXYZ`.

Comment: So in short, your library file should be `libmylib.so`.

Answer (score 3):

`mylib.so` should be `libmylib.so`, else the linker can't find it.

(How about having a look at the libraries already installed on your system instead of making wrong assumptions?)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong when I copied it here : my library's name's actually "libmylib.so" (I replace its real name by "mylib", but its complete name is "libSocketTCP.so")

Comment: Could you please answer my question, now I fixed it?

Comment: @user2153863 Naturellement :) So. In first place, what does "doesn't work" mean? Is it still that the linker can't find the library?